# Make python program accessible by AWS

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, post, amazon-ec2, get

I have a python function and I want to be able to call it from my website. Basically, the website should send inputs to the python function which sends the output back to be displayed on the website.

I am currently thinking about using an AWS lambda function to hold the python function (since I don't want to set up an EC2 instance, etc.). What is the best way to transfer the input/output (a JSON file)? I am currently using S3 to hold the data, but considering HTTP GET/POST, etc.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Amazon API Gateway to setup RESTful API for calling your lambda function.

[Link to the official tutorial](https://aws.amazon.com/api-gateway/getting-started/)